# How to preserve utt-8 signature with requeststream.write

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, utf-8

I'm using the following code to send an XML file by FTP:

```
        var request = (FtpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(destination);

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, Password);

        byte[] fileContents;

        using (StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(originpath + filename))
        {
            fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        }

        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        }
```

This seems to work, except the format of the file at the origin is utf-8 *with signature*, and it's *without signature* at the destination.

I've tried to preserve the utf encoding, but I seem to have lost the BOM.

Is this a problem with my code - specifically, with the way that requeststream.write works?

Comment: FTP has a text and a binary mode.  I think it defaults to text.  You need to change FTP to binary mode.  request.UseBinary = true;

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. It's still being reported as without signature. The files are identical apart from that. Also, I've got Filezilla working in binary as default, so I don't tihnk it's being corrupted when I retrieve it from the destination site...

Comment: Do you means the signature is the first line of xml (the ident line)?  FTP just sends text so it is impossible for FTP to truncate one line.

Comment: I'm not sure. All I really know is that EmEditor is reporting the format of the original file as uft-8 with signature, and the destination file as utf-8 without signature. If I try to compare the files, I get a warning tell me they are a different format, but apart from the signature thing they appear to be identical.

Comment: Xml is text and you can view the files with any text editor like NotePad.  I would compare the source and destination file manually to  see what is different.  Maybe use beyond compare.  The EmEditor warning is vague.  I don't know if the signature is the first line of the xml or the soap 509 signature.  It may be that you are truncating the end of the message and missing bytes.  So I would check the size of the file to see how many bytes are being dropped.

Comment: Why would you need a BOM with XML?